# Is it possible to debug CImageList::Read(CArchive *)?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++, mfc

[`CImageList::Read(CArchive *)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/cimagelist-class?view=vs-2019#read) returns zero in my code.

Since `Read` only returns zero, without additional information about the error, I was wondering if I can somehow debug into the `Read` with <kbd>F11</kbd>?

I have disabled Just My Code Debugging but debugging continues as if I did nothing.  I got *winctrl2.cpp not found* from Visual Studio. It offered me to click on *Browse*, which I did, and have pointed it to the file.

Now it works, I can enter the `Read` method, but in it, it asks for the file *commctrl.inl*, offering me the popup in which I must enter the file path.

I am using Visual Studio 2019.

*If you know alternative solution on how to get helpful info about the error, I will consider accepting it as an answer as well.*

Comment: *"I was wondering if I can somehow debug into the `Read` with F11?"* - What happened when you tried?

Comment: @IInspectable: Nothing, debugging continued as if I have never pressed F11

Comment: Have you [disabled Just My Code debugging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/just-my-code?view=vs-2019#BKMK_Enable_or_disable_Just_My_Code)?

Comment: Just type $err,hr (=Pseudovariable) in the variable window to see the last Errorcode produced by Win-API.

Comment: @IInspectable: OK, I did that. Still the same effect, but I get *winctrl2.cpp not found* from Visual Studio. I am Googling for a solution as I type this...

Comment: So then, let Visual Studio know, where those files reside. A Visual Studio installation that includes MFC also comes with the MFC source code.

Comment: @IInspectable: I have clicked on the Browse button and added the path to that file. I was able to F11 into Read, but now popup window asks me to enter the path to *commctrl.inl* and I can not find that file at the moment. I am still trying to solve that one. Since I was able to F11 into `Read()`, should I close this question and post new one about the new issue I face?

Comment: *commctrl.inl* is part of the Windows SDK.

Comment: The full path for "winctrl2.cpp" should be like this: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio XX\VC\atlmfc\src\mfc\winctrl2.cpp" (XX is 15, 16, or something, corresponding to your Visual Studio 2019) Open that file, put break point in `CImageList::Read`

Comment: Took a short look into the MDF source (winctrl2.cpp) and found that there's not much to debug in there. `CImageList::Read()` just calls `ImageList_Read()` (decl in commctrl.h) and returns TRUE if successful. So there must be sth wrong with your stream. The documentation doesn't specifically mention if this function does set the Windows error-code (`GetLastError()`), but you can try it.

Comment: @ConstantineGeorgiou: I think you are right.

Comment: You can always open the disassembly, and single-step through the disassembly. This works for *any* code, including code that's internal to the OS.